# Location.href and urlrewriting

Tags: javascript

Hi I have urlrewriting in my application. so it would look like this;

> www.mydomain.com/pmillio

I am using location.href to get the url in one of my functions,

location.href gives me www.mydomain.com/pmillio

However i need to change the url so it looks like this instead;

> www.mydomain.com/user-profile.aspx?username=pmillio

How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
location = 'user-profile.aspx?username=' + (location.pathname).replace('/','');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var url = "www.mydomain.com/pmillio";
var split = url.split("/");
url = split[0] + "/user-profile.aspx?username=" + split[1];
```

It splits the URL string on the slash, then builds a new string based on the first part of the URL (everything before the slash), adds the `user-profile.aspx" part, and appends the username (the last part of the original URL) to the end.

Comment: That seems waay too complicated ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the user to be able to go to /[username] but actually serve the page /user_profile.aspx?username=[username],  correct?

You're not going to be able to do this in javascript. You need to do this on the server with [Url Rewrite](http://google.com/?q=url%20rewrite%20iis) on IIS.